# The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination. ASP NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Im working with json and write the data same as the model, but still recieving the error 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.'

my model code

```
public partial class VerTempWellTrajectory
{
    [Key] public int No { get; set; }
    public string? Well { get; set; }
    public string? TrajectoryYesNo { get; set; }
    public string? WellType { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
    public string? FileAdviceToBeDigitized { get; set; }
    public string? Remark { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RowCreated { get; set; }
}
```

my json

```
function Save() {
    var fail = {
        title: 'Data insert fail',
        message: 'refresh page to save again',
        position: 'topRight'
    };
    console.log(_oSeismics);
    if (_oSeismics.length > 0) {
        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "../DummyTempAdd/SaveDummyWT/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { data: _oSeismics },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function (data) {

            alert("Successfully saved.");

        });

        ajaxRequest.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) { 
            iziToast.error(
                    fail
                ); 
        });

    }

    else {

        iziToast.error(
                    fail
                );

    }

}

function NewSeismicObj() {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
    var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

    console.log(dateTime)
    
    var oSeismic = {
        
        No: "",
        Well: "",
        TrajectoryYesNo:"",
        WellType: "",
        Status: "",
        FileAdviceToBeDigitized: "",
        Remark: "",
        RowCreated: dateTime
            
    };console.log(dateTime)

    return oSeismic;

}
```

my controller

```
public JsonResult SaveDummyWT(List<VerTempWellTrajectory> data)
    {
        _WTt = _db.SaveDummyWT(data);
        TempData["success"] = "Inserted to Temporary Table successfully";
        return Json(_WTt);
    }
```

i send from the controller to service file
here is the service code

```
public List<VerTempWellTrajectory> SaveDummyWT(List<VerTempWellTrajectory> data)
    {
        _dbContext.BulkInsert(data);
        return data;
    }
```

on other process it run as it is, but in this model always recieving the error i mentioned
down here I have the screenshot of the data passed from the json
[Data passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYfNo.png)
and the screenchot of tables design
[Table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaqol.png)

I add my modelbuilder code below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VerDummyWellTrajectory>(entity =>
        {
            

            entity.ToTable("VER_DUMMY_WELL__TRAJECTORY", "db_owner");

            entity.Property(e => e.FileAdviceToBeDigitized)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("FILE_ADVICE_TO_BE_DIGITIZED");

            entity.Property(e => e.No)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("NO");

            entity.Property(e => e.Remark)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("REMARK");

            entity.Property(e => e.RowCreated)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("ROW_CREATED");

            entity.Property(e => e.Status)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("STATUS");

            entity.Property(e => e.TrajectoryYesNo)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("TRAJECTORY_Yes_No");

            entity.Property(e => e.Well)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("WELL");

            entity.Property(e => e.WellType)
                .HasMaxLength(512)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("WELL_TYPE");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your column the same as your columns in your database if it will work.

Other option is to try mapping your property to the column of your entity model since your model property is different from your columns

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VerTempWellTrajectory>()
            .ToTable("tablename_in_database")
            .Property(m => m.Well)
            .HasColumnName("WELL");
```

Comment: my model builder already same as you and same as the column name
'entity.Property(e => e.Well)
                    .HasMaxLength(512)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("WELL");'
thatis the model builder code